# How to disable the NUM/CAPS lock and unlock notification in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications

I have a [AVELL G1555 FOX](https://avell.com.br/g1555-fox) with Windows 10.

I recently bought Windows 10 PRO and after install it this notifications becomes to show:

[image: Windows 10 notification]

How can I disable them?

Comment: The notification in question is not being generated by Windows.  Which means you have more than likely, OEM software, that is generating that notification.

Comment: I found a service `OSDSrv.exe` running a child process named `OSD.exe`, I stopped it and the problem was solved. It was installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\OEM\OSD`, I believe it's a notebook vendor application.

Comment: You should submit an answer to your own question.  The only part I played was to indicate it was NOT being generated by Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a service `OSDSrv.exe` running a child process named `OSD.exe`, I stopped it and the problem was solved. 
It was installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\OEM\OSD`, I believe it's a notebook vendor application not from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a Lenovo laptop, try disabling the **LenovoUtility** from statup. This seems to control the On-screen keyboard messege for Num Lock, Caps Lock and some other stuff

Comment: Welcome to superuser; This does not provide an answer to the question as the computer is different. However this could help someone with a Lenovo but would generally be a comment. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post, so keep coming back. again welcome to superuser.